# UIImage circle in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I'm following the the normal approach in Turing an image into circle :

```
   image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.width/2.0f;
    image.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    image.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    image.clipsToBounds = YES ;
```

However when I used it in cells, first time it shows in Simi-perfect circle, but when I scroll to show new cells , all will be in perfect circle shape.
so my question is : why the first visible cells appear in a Simi-cirlce shape ? 
[image]
This is how it looks like first time , but if I refresh or reload the page, everything is fine

Comment: Is the height for row at greater or equal than the image?

Comment: Check the dimensions of the imageview.
Double check the constraints applied.

Comment: for that imageview should be square it requires for circle

Comment: @JRB the image aspect ratio is 1:1 already, something else is up

Comment: can you display problem screenshots? because your code i think right

Comment: @JRB ok , lemme re-do the scenario

Comment: @JRB there you go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165146/discussion-between-jrb-and-mimma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this way

like in custom cell class

```
class ProfilePicCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        image.layer.cornerRadius =  image.frame.width / 2
        image.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

in **Objective C** add this method in  custom cell class

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
 super.awakeFromNib()

 image.layer.cornerRadius =  image.frame.width / 2
}
```

Comment: can I use this concept on my custom tableview cell ? I'm using my own image inside the uitablecellview

Comment: The best place to do layout is in `UIViews`'s `layoutSubview`. If you do it in `awakeFromNib` or other methods that are called before `layoutSubviews` then your image might not have it´s final size yet. This is usually the case when working with storyboard and constraints, but is always a good practise to follow. Consider @Milan Nosáľ solution instead.

Answer (score 3):

Override `layoutSubviews` in the cell and after calling `super.layoutSubviews` update the `image.layer.cornerRadius` there. Then when the layout of the cell is updated after the cell gets visible, the corner radius will be updated accordingly.

So in swift, in your cell implementantion you would do something like:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    // now the frames were recalculated, and we can update cornerRadius
    image.layer.cornerRadius = image.bounds.size.width / 2.0
}
```